# Returning all key:value pairs from object array that key includes underscore in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have rows that contain data in form like this:

```
{
 id:"id",
 param:"street1",
 param:"street2",
 param_eu:"street",
 param_ru:"street",
},
{
 id:"id2",
 param:"street1",
 param:"street2",
 param_fr:"street",
 param_cz:"street",
},
```

I would like to pick only pairs that contain "_" and only keep the country as key name, like this:

```
{ 
 eu:"street",
 ru:"street"
},
{ 
 fr:"street",
 cz:"street"
},
```

Managed to get it done with multiple inner for loops but that is huge. Any better solutions?

Comment: show us the code (your attempt)

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype).

Comment: Someone's going to tell you to use `reduce`. Don't, it's just added complication. Use `map` and in the callback a `for-in` loop (or `for-of` on `Object.keys`), or `map` where the callback uses `Object.fromEntries`, `Object.entries`, and `filter`. (In that latter one you'd also need another `map` to change the key value, so the loop is probably simpler.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on your array to map each object to a new object. The new objects are created using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries),  [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and `.map()`. You can use  these methods as follows:

1. Use `Object.entries()` to obtain an array  of `[[key, value],...]` pairs from your object.
2. On the above key-value pair array, use `.filter()` to obtain only the keys that contain an underscore in them by checking if the `key` [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) an underscore `"_"`
3. Once you have filtered your array, use `.map()` on your filtered key-value array to map each inner array (ie: `[key, value]`) to a new array, where everything to the left of the underscore is removed. To do this, you can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) your key using `"_"` to form an array of two parts - the `"param"` & the alpha country code. You can use [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to obtain the last string in your array of parts (ie: the alpha country code)
4. Wrap this filtered/mapped array of key-value pairs in a call to `Object.fromEntries()`. Since this takes an array of `[[key, value], ...]` pairs, it will be able to build an object for you, where each inner `[key, value]` array is converted into a `{key: value, ...}` in the resulting object.

See example below:

```js
const arr = [{ id: "id", param: "street1", param: "street2", param_eu: "street", param_ru: "street", }, { id: "id2", param: "street1", param: "street2", param_fr: "street", param_cz: "street", } ];

const res = arr.map(
  obj => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(
      ([key]) => key.includes("_")
    ).map(([key, val])=> [key.split("_").pop(), val])
  )
);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list, and every time, reduce the object properties:

```js
const data = [
  { id:"id", param:"street1", param:"street2", param_eu:"street", param_ru:"street" },
  { id:"id2", param:"street1", param:"street2", param_fr:"street", param_cz:"street" }
];

// iterate over objects
const res = data.reduce((countries, item) => {
  // reduce object properties
  const itemWithCountries = Object.entries(item)
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
      if(key.includes('_')) acc[key.split('_').pop()] = value;
      return acc;
    }, {});
  // push reduced object
  if(Object.keys(itemWithCountries).length > 0) countries.push(itemWithCountries);
  return countries;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map new object by getting all entries from the objects, get the one you want and build object from the entries as new objects.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: "id", param: "street1", param: "street2", param_eu: "street", param_ru: "street" }, { id: "id2", param: "street1", param: "street2", param_fr: "street", param_cz: "street" }],
    result = array.map(object => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(object)
        .filter(([key]) => key.includes('_'))
    ));

console.log(result);
```